# Trying to include a header in Visual Studio 2010, unable to compile error LNK2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gnu

I started a new project for that alone under "empty project".
I was trying to include a combinatronics algorithm from
http://www.aconnect.de/friends/editions/computer/combinatoricode_e.html

the only files in the project are "main.cpp" which is a copy paste of
http://www.aconnect.de/friends/editions/computer/generate/comb_norep_lex_example.c

and a header "_generate.h" which is directly copied from
http://www.aconnect.de/friends/editions/computer/generate/_generate.h

the errors I get are:

Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl gen_comb_norep_lex_next(unsigned char *,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (?gen_comb_norep_lex_next@@YAHPAEEE@Z) referenced in function _main
C:\Users\user\Documents\pr1\pr2\pr2\main.obj    pr2

Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl gen_comb_norep_lex_init(unsigned char *,unsigned char,unsigned char)" (?gen_comb_norep_lex_init@@YAHPAEEE@Z) referenced in function _main    C:\Users\user\Documents\pr1\pr2\pr2\main.obj    pr2

I have looked through similar questions, but none of the solutions worked for me.

Thanks

Comment: The header file only *declares* the functions, you need a source file where those functions are *defined* as well, and include that in your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Joachim Pileborg comment is correct, I didn't add the actual algorithm. My bad.